# Why does bundler update gems when it knows the gemfile requires a specific version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

This seems to happen a lot. I run bundle update or bundle install and for one reason or another I often get something like this:

> You have already activated kgio 2.8.0, but your Gemfile requires kgio
>   2.7.4. Using bundle exec may solve this

I then have to go and run: `sudo gem uninstall kgio` and select kgio 2.8.0 to uninstall it.

Why does bundler even update the gem if it knows my gemfile locks those gems to a specific version. I NEVER install gems outside of the gemfile and bundler so Im not circumventing its conventions. I do have another project on my machine, but I havent ran a bunle update on that project in a long time -- is there some mix up there? Has this happened to anyone else? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think I found my problem. I seems to be a git issue where my trunk and branch have different versions of the same gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually `bundle update` the gems specified (all gems, if none are specified), ignoring the previously installed gems specified in the Gemfile.lock.

whereas `bundle install` will fetch all remote sources, but use the dependencies specified in the Gemfile.lock instead of resolving dependencies.

and use

```
gem cleanup
```

This command will remove (uninstall) all the versions of a gem, except for the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle update`, installs newer versions of your gems and states that in your Gemfile.lock. `bundle install` just makes sure you have the correct versions installed. I suppose you are running bundle install in projects with different locked versions for kgio.